# Negative question with "no"

Tags: grammar

What should I say to doubtedly ask if there are words used in a movie?

a) There are no words in the movie, aren't they?

b) There are no words in the movie, are they?

Comment: It would be fine to say "There are no words in the movie, are there?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use "no", you'd use "not any" which in this case becomes "aren't any". You would also use "there" not "they" at the end.

> There aren't any words in the movie, are there?

Answer (score 1):

There **aren't any words** in the movie, **are there**?

There are **no words** in the movie, **are there**? [negative meaning]

There are words in the movie, aren't there?

**If the question is negative the tag is reversed**; **if the statement is declarative, the tag is interrogative**. Ben Harris' one is good too and follows the negative pattern.

Just remember the trick: negative=inverted tag
declarative=interrogative [reverse the form of the be verb] tag

This pattern is the same for all sentences in English:
They could go if they wanted to go, couldn't they?
They couldn't go if they wanted to go, could they?

We should do the work now, shouldn't we?
We shouldn't do the work now, should we?

The tag is always the helping verb or modal.

I  hope you get this, don't I?

:)